# Glare effect different when rendered than from viewport

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, glare

No idea why this happens, the glare/lense effect I added looks fine in the viewport with the Compositor enabled, but when I render it looks way different :

Viewport Display :
[image: Viewport Display]

Render Display :
[image: Render Display]

I'm using EEVEE, here's my Compositor setup :
[image: Compositor setup]

Here's a minimal test file showing the problem :
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you enable *Bloom* in your properties?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Hello, I did. However it shouldn't matter because the bloom comes from the Glare Node I'm using in the Compositor, so it appears either way in viewport, and never appears acorrectly in render.

Comment: i thought the glare node only works for Cycles

Comment: No it also works in EEVEE. It's just that for some reason, the render and the viewport don't match

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? (only share the useful objects)

Comment: Hello @moonboot, thanks, I added a minimal test file in my post !

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that some nodes still don't work correctly in real time viewport compositing, so maybe you should better enable the Background option of the Compositor and only count on it for the moment?

Comment: right. I think I figured out what happens : in Viewport, the Glare Node is actually emulated through a Bloom effect, which does not look the same as the actual Glare effect in the Render. My solution is to just setup the Bloom right and not use Glare.